# Need multiple value select in from of key value pair in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

i have a requirement to select values in form of key-value pairs in the Jenkins. I wan to 2 dropdowns and second dropdown to be dynamic. So first dropdown will have module names and upon selecting any modules its corresponding components should dynamically loaded in second dropdown, so likewise I want to select multiple module and its components and then run a script.

Am able to do for single module like I select a single module and then from second drop-down I can select its components but not able to do multiple to multiple

Comment: Have you looked at the `Dynamic Parameter` or `Active Choices Parameter` plugins? One of them will have what you want to do

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.